# Gmail "Send Mail As" from a Google Apps account, using an alias

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, smtp

I have two Google mail accounts: my main account (`myself@gmail.com`) and a Google Apps account (`myself@g.mydomain.com`). I would like to use my primary `gmail.com` address to sign in and receive all mail, but still be able to send mail from **an alias** of my Google Apps account (`myself_fullname@mydomain.com` as opposed to `myself@g.mydomain.com`).

Gmail provides these settings:

[image]

If I choose "Send through Gmail", I can send from `myself_fullname@mydomain.com`, but **recipients see "sent by `myself@gmail.com` on behalf of `myself_fullname@mydomain.com`"**.

If I choose "Send through `mydomain.com` SMTP servers", then I'm forced to use the following SMTP settings:

[image]

This removes the "on behalf of" header, but now **my emails are sent from `myself@g.mydomain.com` rather than my alias `myself_fullname@mydomain.com`**.

Is there any way to use the alias, but avoid "on behalf of"?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the only solution was to **create another user**, for which the primary email uses the alias domain.

In your case, connect to the admin console for `g.mydomain.com`.

- First, remove the email alias you say you have set up for your first account.
- Create a new user with the same name as the first account, and for its primary email address you should be able to choose `@mydomain.com`.
- Log in with this new account (the username should be `myself_fullname@mydomain.com`), set your password and don't forget to enable mail forwarding.
- Finally, set the settings of your Gmail account (`myself@gmail.com`) that you mentioned to :

  - SMTP Server: `smtp.gmail.com`
  - Username: `myself_fullname@mydomain.com`
  - Password: the new password

Job done.

Comment: Thats working. good idea.

Answer (score 2):

To make this work, the aliased email address (*myself_fullname@mydomain.com*) needs to be configured as a "Send mail as" address in both your regular Gmail account (*myself@gmail.com*) **and** your Google Apps account (*myself@g.mydomain.com*).

When you send an email from your Google Apps email alias while being logged in to your regular Gmail account, the following happens:

1. Google authenticates you at *smtp.google.com* with your domain credentials.
2. Then it tries to send the email from the email alias.
3. The Google Apps domain account does not know or care that you have the alias configured in your regular Gmail account. If it does not see the alias in its own configuration as well, it will always use the default domain name instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Sending from vanilla Gmail through my G Suite domain, my primary G Suite email address insisted on appearing in the headers of outbound messages until I added the custom From address in the G Suite account as well.

Comment: A lot of searching and I totally agree. This should be the accepted answer. Establishing the Send As setup for the alias in BOTH your personal gmail and your G Suite gmail accounts is required.